# How to Scan ID number on a Read-Only property in Richedit

Tags: c++, mfc, readonly

I am going to change the property of Richedit into "read-only" property. And no user will be able to type in the Richedit. Unless they scan their ID. My question is how am I going to scan an ID number or barcode on "read-only" property ?

Comment: First you have to find out how this scanned ID is coming into your program. For instance, I've worked with barcode scanners that simply input as if someone was typing on a keyboard. If that's your case it may be tricky to distinguish which input you're dealing with. Alternatively you might be dealing with an integration that brings in the scanned input through some other means. Without knowing about the input method, there's not much help you can get beyond wild guesses.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I just want to scan the ID number and the user will not able to type anything. Like typing their ID number.

Comment: Soujds like you are asking two questions. 1. How to get the scanned id from the user. 2. How to update the property of a readonly rtf control.

Comment: @PJiwon why are you using a RichEdit to receive a scanned ID in the first place? There are undoubtedly better ways to get the ID.

Comment: I just want a restriction. The user will not able to type on a richeditctrl. They just scan only. Can you help me with this ? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @PJiwon My point is, depending on how your scanner actually works, there may be other ways to get the scanned ID from it. Maybe it can put the ID on the clipboard. Maybe it can send the ID in a dedicated window message. Maybe it has its own API library you can interface with. Receiving the scanned ID via keystrokes to a UI control is not very reliable or flexible, but some scanners do work that way. You might try using a low-level keyboard hook, or a Raw Input hook, to intercept the keystrokes before they reach your UI.